# Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [MTU and Fragmentation](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3524/mtu-and-fragmentation)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [IOS - Nat from a VRF to WAN interface in global routing table](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3309/ios-nat-from-a-vrf-to-wan-interface-in-global-routing-table)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [WEP 152bit encryption key.... Why?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3354/wep-152bit-encryption-key-why)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [IPv6 Multicast vs Unicast](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3427/ipv6-multicast-vs-unicast)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Remote sniffing with ERSPAN to the desktop](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3274/erspan-to-the-desktop)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Multiple sub-nets behind a router](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3321/multiple-sub-nets-behind-a-router)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Interface capabilities: CISCO 2960S vs WS-X4648](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3406/interface-capabilities-cisco-2960s-vs-ws-x4648)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- ["Local Policy Denied Prefixes" in 'show ip bgp neighbor' output](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3217/local-policy-denied-prefixes-in-show-ip-bgp-neighbor-output)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Solution for network inventory?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3562/solution-for-network-inventory)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Distinguishing google drive from other https traffic](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3280/distinguishing-google-drive-from-other-https-traffic)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---